# Construct a corpus from a Wikipedia database dump

Tags: python, wikipedia

First, I aquired and used for this task the file `enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2`. (From [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/).)

Then I placed this file, unzipped, in the same directory of my `.py` file, and I called it as `WikiCorpus.py`. The following is the `python` code taken from [Building a Wikipedia Text Corpus for Natural Language Processing](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/11/building-wikipedia-text-corpus-nlp.html):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun May  3 11:33:46 2020

@author: Standard
"""

"""
Creates a corpus from Wikipedia dump file.
Inspired by:
https://github.com/panyang/Wikipedia_Word2vec/blob/master/v1/process_wiki.py
"""

import sys
from gensim.corpora import WikiCorpus

def make_corpus(in_f, out_f):

    """Convert Wikipedia xml dump file to text corpus"""

    output = open(out_f, 'w')
    wiki = WikiCorpus(in_f)

    i = 0
    for text in wiki.get_texts():
        output.write(bytes(' '.join(text), 'utf-8').decode('utf-8') + '\n')
        i = i + 1
        if (i % 10000 == 0):
            print('Processed ' + str(i) + ' articles')
    output.close()
    print('Processing complete!')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print('Usage: python make_wiki_corpus.py <wikipedia_dump_file> <processed_text_file>')
        sys.exit(1)
    in_f = sys.argv[1]
    out_f = sys.argv[2]
    make_corpus(in_f, out_f)
```

But when I go to execute it, I obtain the following error:

```
Usage: python make_wiki_corpus.py <wikipedia_dump_file> <processed_text_file>
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: How do you execute it? From your code it seems like you didn't put in two arguments. Have you tried printing `argv`? What have you tried to fix this? Have you tried the example input `python make_wiki_corpus enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 wiki_en.txt`?

Comment: @asdfCYBER, from `sys.argv` I obtain `['C:/Users/Standard/Desktop/Mydir/WikiCorpus.py']`

Comment: did you try the example input listed above? It looks like you do not provide the in_f and out_f parameters when running. Edit: just read that you unzipped and renamed things, the input file should not be unzipped according to your very own source. Try reading your tutorial more carefully.

Comment: @asdfCYBER, thank you! I followed your suggestions